# fastapi Error: AssertionError: Status code 204 must not have a response body

Tags: python, fastapi

I have this code using FastAPI:

```
@router.put(
    "/api/v1/me/language",
    tags=["users"],
    responses={
        400: {"model": BadRequest},
        401: {"model": Unauthorized},
        403: {"model": Forbidden},
        404: {"model": NotFound},
        500: {"model": InternalServerError}
    },
    response_class=fastapi.responses.ORJSONResponse,
    status_code=204,
)
async def patch_me_users_language(
    request: Request, session=fastapi.Depends(get_db)
) -> NO_CONTENT_RESPONSE:
    content_bytes = await request.body()
    content = content_bytes.decode("utf-8").upper()

    if content in set(COUNTRIES):
        db_result = DBUser.get_by_uuid(
            request.state.user_uuid, session
        )
        if db_result:
            try:
                db_result.update({"language": content}, session)
                # Tried it already with 'return Response(status_code=HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT.value)'
                return
            except pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError as e:
                return http_err.UnprocessableEntity(detail=e.errors()).render()
        else:
            return http_err.InternalServerError(
                detail=f"User for this valid token does not exist."
            ).render()
    else:
        return http_err.UnprocessableEntity(
            detail=[
                {
                    "loc": ["body"],
                    "msg": "Expected the content to contain a valid language/country code",
                    "type": "value_error",
                }
            ]
        ).render()
```

wherein `http_err` is an instance of a `HttpErrors` subclass, defined as follows:

```
class HttpErrors(pydantic.BaseModel):
    """
    Base class for HTTP error responses. The render method is used to translate instances of this class into
    fastapi.responses.ORJSONResponse responses.
    """
    status: int
    detail: str

    def render(self) -> fastapi.responses.ORJSONResponse:
        """
        Translates a class instance into a fastapi.responses.ORJSONResponse
        :return: fastapi.responses.ORJSONResponse
        """
        logger.info(f"Returned error response: status: {self.status}, msg: {self.content}")
        return fastapi.responses.ORJSONResponse(
            status_code=self.status,
            content=self.content()
        )

    def content(self):
        return {'detail': self.detail}

    def json_content(self):
        return json.dumps(self.content())


class BadRequest(HttpErrors):
    status = 400


class Unauthorized(HttpErrors):
    status = 401


class Forbidden(HttpErrors):
    status = 403


class NotFound(HttpErrors):
    status = 404


class UnprocessableEntity(pydantic.BaseModel):
    status = 422
    detail: List[dict]

    def render(self) -> fastapi.responses.ORJSONResponse:
        return fastapi.responses.ORJSONResponse(
            status_code=self.status,
            content={'detail': self.detail}
        )
```

This worked in FastAPI 0.85.2, but in 0.104.1 I get an error that says

```
AssertionError: Status code 204 must not have a response body
```

Per the comment in the code, I tried to replace the empty `return` with `return Response(status_code=HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT.value)`, but this has no effect.

How should I handle the empty response correctly? I assume it depends on the model definition inside the annotation (`router.put(...)`), but couldn't find anything here.

Comment: Did you try to check, with logging or a debugger or perhaps by reading a stack trace, what code path is taken in the case that causes a problem? Were you able to determine what the response body consists of, or where it's coming from?

Comment: This is your "success" response, right?  Why aren't you sending back a success code with something like `{ "status": "ok" }`?  That's the normal way of handling a successful transaction.

Comment: Because I replicate an existing application which returns it that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
response_class=fastapi.responses.ORJSONResponse,
status_code=204,
```

I guess, When your return status_code is 204 (no content), you can't specify response model.
Try to remove response model

```
@router.put(
    "/api/v1/me/language",
    tags=["users"],
    responses={
        400: {"model": BadRequest},
        401: {"model": Unauthorized},
        403: {"model": Forbidden},
        404: {"model": NotFound},
        500: {"model": InternalServerError}
    },
    status_code=204,
)
async def patch_me_users_language(
    request: Request, session=fastapi.Depends(get_db)
) -> None:
...
```

In successful case use `return None` or just `return` to exit function

Comment: Thanks, removing response_class and the type annotation of the return value (or change it to None) worked